# YII2 Activedataprovider custom template

Tags: yii2

Let's assume that we have three tables, tbl_student ,tbl_lesson and tbl_score(student_id, lesson_id, score).

for Activedataprovider, we have:

```
$query = \app\models\Score::find()
    ->joinWith('student', false)
    ->joinWith('lesson', false);

$provider = new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $array,
]);

echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]);
```

So it gives an output with columns : student_id, lesson_id, score:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td> student_id </td>
    <td> lesson_id </td>
    <td> score </td>  
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> 99.5 </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> 2 </td>
    <td> 54 </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> 3 </td>
    <td> 87 </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td> 2 </td>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> 76 </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td> 2 </td>
    <td> 2 </td>
    <td> 84 </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td> 2 </td>
    <td> 3 </td>
    <td> 69 </td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

But what I want is to display students in the first COLUMN, and lessons in the first ROW and then display the associated scores in the body of the table:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>student_id</td>
    <td>lesson_1</td>
    <td>lesson_2</td>
    <td>lesson_3</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>99.5</td>
    <td>54</td>
    <td>87</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>76</td>
    <td>84</td>
    <td>69</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

---

I know that I can use Arraydataprovider, but as said in [Yii2 data providers guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html)

> Note: Compared to Active Data Provider and SQL Data Provider, array data provider is less efficient because it requires loading all data into the memory.

---

What I want:
[image: generated by Arraydataprovider]

but I want to do it using Activedataprovider

Comment: What do you mean with lessons it the first row? Could you add a sketch of your required GridView to your question? According to [the docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#grid-columns) you have to configure the columns, i.e. order and content of each column. Have a look. And you will probably want to prefetch data with joinWith('student', true)...

Comment: @robsch thanks for your comment; I updated my post and I hope it's more clear .

Comment: Okay. One thing needs to be clarified: Are the colums fixed to lesson_1, lesson_2, lesson_3 and is available for each student or is this dynamic (this would make it harder)?

Comment: @robsch the lesson_*, are the lessons, lesson ids for example.because I could not assign numbers as attributes, I prefixed them with 'lesson_'; so they are indeed dynamic.

Comment: But are those dynamic or are they determined by something?

Comment: @robsch dynamically read from database, all lesson_id s which are stored in tbl_score

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102256/discussion-between-robsch-and-pooria).

Comment: Is this similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27442314/57091 ?

Comment: @robsch yes I thinks yes :)
I must improve my search ability. but no answer there.

Comment: Sure, there is an answer. But I don't know if it helps. At least it is about dynamic columns, with which you have to deal as well.

Comment: @robsch at last I stopped at Arraydataprovider . until I find a better way :) , thanks alotttt