# Yii2 ArrayDataProvider template

Tags: gridview, yii2, dataprovider

I try to display a gridview with a student name in a field of every row and dynamic columns with lessons both.

I have a problem like this:    [YII2 Activedataprovider custom template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35117307/yii2-activedataprovider-custom-template/35815870). I use ArrayDataProvider. But I don't understand, how I can solve my task.

I need an example with code or some algorithm.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flFE9.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case ,you need use ArrayDataProvider as you well said.

1. You need three querys , students,lessons,notes and id relaccion for all.
2. A function in controller that createRelaccion
3. In your view you need

   ```
   $provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
                       'allModels' => $MyCustomModel,
                       'pagination' => [
                           'pageSize' => 10,
                       ],
                   ]);

    foreach ($ArrayLessons as $content)
           {
               $columns[]=[
                        'label'=>$content,'format'=>'raw',
                        'value' => function($datas,$r,$t,$h){
                           return '10,11, the exam note';
                   }
                    ];                
           }
   ```

   and echo

   ```
   echo GridView::widget([
                       'dataProvider' =>  $provider,
                       'id'=>'Provider_'.$count,
                       'columns' =>$columns,
                       'pjax' => true,
                       'pjaxSettings' => ['options' => []],
                       'panel' => [
                           'heading' => '<h3 class="panel-title">'.$dat[2].'</h3>',
                       ],
                      'toolbar' => [
                       ['content'=>$repeat],
                       ], 
                       ]);
   ```

Comment: I have got relaccion in my controller such as:
$data = [
$studentName1 => [ name => 'studentName1', date1 => 10, date2 => 15, ...],
$studentName2 => [  name => 'studentName2', date1 => 5, date2 => 25, ...]
];
I don't know it's correct or not.

How I'm using 'foreach' for fill the $columns with my $data array? I need unique dates and unique names for solution this task, but I don't know how I can get it through cycles.